# Al crear una cookie en java age la pone a -1

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

Al hacer login en mi pagina web me envia al doPost de mi servlet y en este momento genero una cookie llamando al funcion:

```
public void createCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String name, String value, int time)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(name, value);

    newCookie.setMaxAge(time);
    newCookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(newCookie);
}
```

Una vez creadas las cookies hago la redireccion a un nuevo servlet

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("hola));
```

En el navegador se muestra correctamente la cookie pero al intentar recuperarla en el nuevo servlet se recuperan pero el valor de maxAge siempre es de -1 para todas las cookies.

```
for (Cookie c : request.getCookies())
{
   c.getMaxAge();//--> siempre me devuelve -1           
}
```

Gracias de antemano